# Magento - rewrite hierarchy

Tags: magento

What is the config required to rewrite a class that is already rewriting another class in magento?

For example, There is a community module doing the following:

```
<models>
    <modulea>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <session>CompanyA_ModuleA_Model_Adminhtml_Session</session>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </modulea>
</models>
```

I want to rewrite the community module and I am trying the following code which is not working:

```
<models>
    <moduleb>
        <class>CompanyB_ModuleB_Model</class>
    </moduleb>
    <modulea>
            <rewrite>
                <adminhtml_session>CompanyB_ModuleB_Model_Adminhtml_Session</adminhtml_session>
            </rewrite>
    </modulea>
</models>
```

What is wrong with this

Comment: This cannot be the correct syntax. xpath should be `global/models/adminhtml/rewrite/session` (no modulea or moduleb in there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carefull at your rewrite XML syntax, you have an error. It should like :

```
<modulea>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <adminhtml_session>CompanyA_ModuleA_Model_Adminhtml_Session</session>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </modulea>
```

and

```
<moduleb>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <adminhtml_session>CompanyB_ModuleB_Model_Adminhtml_Session</session>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </moduleb>
```

Next you'll need to extends the Good PHP class in the good order. FOr example if you want CompanyA extending/rewriting CompanyB :

CompanyA file :

```
class CompanyA_ModuleA_Model_Adminhtml_Session extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Session {
```

CompanyB Model php file :

```
class CompanyB_ModuleB_Model_Adminhtml_Session extends CompanyA_ModuleA_Model_Adminhtml_Session {
```

Last thing, to be sure that the rewrite is done in the good order (when doing a `Mage::getModel('adminhtml/session')` you want to retrieve the CompanyB class and not the COmpanyA one), you'll need to define which module depends on which. YOu do that in the `app/etc/modules/Company_Module.xml` file.

add for Company A :

```
<depends>
    <Mage_Adminhtml />
</depends>
```

add for Company B :

```
<depends>
    <CompanyA_ModuleA />
</depends>
```

Comment: Should be lowercase d in `<depends />`